# Tensorflow Fit exits with code 1 without any error message

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-3.6, tensorflow-datasets

I'm new to tensorflow. What I'm trying to do is to train a simple neural network to solve the Newton 2 problems, to guess the force value of given mass and acceleration values. The input layer consists of two neurons which are mass and acceleration values. The output layer is the force.

The program just gives a warning, prints some data which I guess the outputs and then exits with code 1. I cannot try anything to solve this problem. Because as I said before I'm new to tensorflow and there is no error message.

Here is the code:

```
   from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
   from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
   import numpy as np
   import pickle


   X = pickle.load(open("Newton2_X.pickle", "rb"))
   y = pickle.load(open("Newton2_y.pickle", "rb"))

   model = Sequential()
   # model.add(Flatten())
   model.add(Dense(2, activation="relu"))
   model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
   model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax"))

   model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

   model.fit(X, y, epochs=3, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=100)
```

Here are the pickle files:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FkKmY4px8oQJkbHYb_Z4y4Lnb1EazkvP?usp=sharing

After this part of the code I've some additional lines to make the network to guess a new value and some print lines. These lines are not executed. In fact, I've found that the 'problem' must be in model.fit(...) part. Because no lines after that line are executed.

Here is the full warning msg that I got from the program:

```
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0816 07:02:05.292823 17652 deprecation.py:506] From C:\Users\SABA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\init_ops.py:1251: calling VarianceScaling.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor
6, 0.2142802901764338, 0.26114980919201514, 0.2451221454091551, 0.19920049739052853, ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to tweak.

Firstly, I don't think the data is the shape that you think it is. You have:

```
X.shape # (45000, 2, 2, 1)
```

`y` is a flat list with 90,000 elements.

Secondly, you are predicting a number (so a regression) but you were trying to use 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' as a loss function which is for classification problems.

I can get your code to run by simply slicing the data down to the shape we need but obviously it won't train as I haven't paired up the correct Xs and ys. You'll need to sort this out properly in the data

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np
import pickle

### TODO - sort this out!
X = pickle.load(open("Newton2_X.pickle", "rb"))[:,0,:,0]
y = np.array(pickle.load(open("Newton2_y.pickle", "rb")))[:45000]
####

model = Sequential()
# model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='mse')

model.fit(X, y, epochs=3, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=100)
```